# discord bot slash command emoij

Tags: python, discord, emoji

this is my script:

````
@bot.tree.command(name="diceroll")
async def diceroll(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    num = random.randint(1, 10)
    await interaction.response.send_message(
        f"```{interaction.user.mention} rolled a dice :game_die:\n--------------\nand it was: {str(num)}```"
    )
````

i tried many things but nothing seemed  to work plshelp

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send a custom emoji, there are a couple ways to do it:

1. You can fetch emoji with `utils.get`. Example:

   ```
    dice_emoji = discord.utils.get(bot.emojis, name="game_die")
   ```

   it returns an `Emoji` class object, which you can format into a string.
2. You can store it as string variable containing it's "text representation". You can get the text representation of a custom emoji by sending it with backslash - `\:game_die:`, and you will get something similar to `<:game_die:1025841396751544441>` which you can successfully hard-code into a string variable and use in formatting.

Note that each custom emoji has it's own unique id, which you have
to find out by yourself.